# After renaming the workbook vba is not working

Tags: vba, excel

I'm still new to VBA, so most of the coding I do are recorded or modified after copying from the internet.

After recording the steps I performed, I noticed that macros will record the file name and the sheet name.

So if I were to open a file that is not similar to the name in the recorded macros, my macros wouldn't work.

For example,  File B is the name that is registered in the macros but I would now wish to perform the macros program on File C but failed.

Is there a way where I can bypass that?

```
Sub trial()

Dim wb, wb2, wb3 As Workbook

Dim fn As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show = -1 Then
fn = .SelectedItems(1)
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fn)
Else
MsgBox "You cancel the process."
End If
End With

Dim SheetName As String

'this is the place i would like to edit
 Windows("SPC July BPW341CL - Copy.csv").Activate
    Sheets("SPC July BPW341CL - Copy").Select
    Sheets("SPC July BPW341CL - Copy").copy after:=Workbooks( _
        "New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsm").Sheets(4)
            Sheets("SPC July BPW341CL - Copy").Activate


SheetName = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") 'Change the format as per your requirement
ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName


    Set wb3 = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    Sheets("Summary").Activate
    Range("A1").Select

        For Each ws In wb3.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "Compare to RGB" And ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
                For i = 1 To 5
                    Selection.Value = ws.Name
                    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there.

At the top, you are creating references to workbooks that you can use later in the code:

```
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fn)
```

This creates a reference to a workbook that you can use in the code later.

When you then have the code:

```
Windows("SPC July BPW341CL - Copy.csv").Activate
Sheets("SPC July BPW341CL - Copy").Select
Sheets("SPC July BPW341CL - Copy").copy after:=Workbooks( _
    "New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsm").Sheets(4)
        Sheets("SPC July BPW341CL - Copy").Activate
```

I presume this is the recorded code?  You should be able to use the references you created earlier:

```
wb.Sheets("SPC July BPW341CL - Copy").Select
wb.Sheets("SPC July BPW341CL - Copy").copy after:=wb2.Sheets(4)
```

etc.

This may not do exactly what you want it to do, because I'm not entirely clear on which sheets you want to copy from which workbook.  But you have the general syntax correct.

You can also index sheets like

```
dim oSheet as worksheet
set osheet = wb.sheets("sheetname") '//to set via name, Or
set oSheet = wb.sheets(4)            '//Or to set via index
```

etc.

Hope this helps.

Edit:  A couple of other points to note:
1.) Always use Option Explicit at the top of your code.
2.)  Dim wb, wb2, wb3 As Workbook - this line doesn't declare three Workbook objects.  Instead, it actually declares two variants and a workbook.  You need to declare them as:  `Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook`

Comment: Thank you very much @ainwood for the answer but I still am unclear of what I should change in my VBA.. Like you say I've made a reference which is fn, is it possible that i replace all the names in the above VBA with fn instead ? For example, 
/Windows("SPC July BPW341CL - Copy.csv").Activate/ is replaced with /Windows("fn").Activate/ ??

As of now I just want to change the filename "SPC July BPW341CL - Copy.csv", so that other workbooks with different names can also be run by the macros.

Comment: Can you please explain what you want the macro to do?  Allow the user to select a Excel file, then what?

Comment: File A is for compiling data, File B to Z or maybe even more are raw data. What i need to do is let the user to select the input file (File B to Z), then copy all the data in it into File A to compile them together in one file. By doing so, there's no way i can list out all the file names as they will vary from time to time depending on the raw data. So is there a way where i can program it in a way so that the user can select any file instead of having to change the file name very single time.